# ObjectInputStream#readObject raises ClassNotFoundException with External Jar classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

So I have a Spring Boot application that loads external jars from the paths below:

```
java -cp "main-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" -Dloader.path="%USERPROFILE%\Addons\" -Dloader.main=moe.ofs.backend.BackendApplication org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

The main jar doesn't know external jars at compile time. External jars are loaded like "plugins" or "addons" by specifying

`-Dloader.path=...`

All of external jars depend on an interface from "main-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", and they are supposed to do object serializations more or less.
The interface is called `Configurable`, and it provides two default methods like these:

```
default <T extends Serializable> void writeFile(T object, String fileName) throws IOException {
    Path configFilePath = configPath.resolve(fileName + ".data");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(configFilePath.toFile());
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
    objectOutputStream.close();
}
```

```
default <T extends Serializable> T readFile(String fileName) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Path configFilePath = configPath.resolve(fileName + ".data");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(configFilePath.toFile());
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
    return (T) objectInputStream.readObject();
}
```

Classes in external jars implement this interface, and they call `readFile()` and `writeFile()`.

`writeFile()` works perfectly fine and doesn't seem to cause any problem; `readFile()`, however, throws a `ClassNotFoundException`, and that's what I'm trying to figure out.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: moe.ofs.addon.navdata.domain.Navaid
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:719)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1922)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1805)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2096)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1624)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:464)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:797)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2232)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2123)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1624)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:464)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at moe.ofs.backend.Configurable.lambda$readFile$0(Configurable.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

After some testing it seems to me that `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown by Class.forName() because the default ClassLoader has a hard time looking for `moe.ofs.addon.navdata.domain.Navaid`, which is the class I'm trying to deserialize.

`Navaid implements Serializable`, and it also has a `static final long serialVersionUID`.

I had hoped that I could solve this by setting a context class loader for current thread, so that `ObjectInputStream` will use Spring Boot class loader to resolve `Navaid` class:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
```

This, when printed out, gives something like

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() = org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7a0b4753
```

Except that `ObjectInputStream#readObject` still throws `ClassNotFoundException`.
If I explicitly make a call to load Navaid class from Spring Boot loader such as:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("moe.ofs.addon.navdata.domain.Navaid");
```

It returns a `Navaid` instance without any issue.

And as expected, when directly calling

```
Class.forName("moe.ofs.addon.navdata.domain.Navaid")
```

a `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown, even if the thread context loader has been explicitly set to `LaunchedURLClassLoader`; `ObjectInputStream#readObject` always tries to resolve the class by making a call to system default classloader to load the class.

Then I tried to load an `ObjectInputStream` using `LaunchedURLClassLoader`, but the instance still used `Class.forName()` from system default class loader.

```
ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();

Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);

System.out.println("Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() = " + Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

Class<?> tClass = getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("java.io.ObjectInputStream");
System.out.println("tClass = " + tClass);

Path configFilePath = configPath.resolve(fileName + ".data");
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(configFilePath.toFile());

Constructor<?> constructor = tClass.getConstructor(InputStream.class);

ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = (ObjectInputStream) constructor.newInstance(fileInputStream);

objectInputStream.readObject();  // throws ClassNotFoundException
```

Any input is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, you should override the method `resolveClass` on `ObjectInputStream`

Something like that:

```
default <T extends Serializable> T readFile(String fileName, ClassLoader loader) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Path configFilePath = configPath.resolve(fileName + ".data");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(configFilePath.toFile());
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream){
       protected Class<?> resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass desc)
                     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
          try {
              return Class.forName(desc.getName(), false, loader);
          } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
              return super.resolveClass(desc);
          }
       }
   };
   return (T) objectInputStream.readObject();
}
```

Never tried it myself, but it is worth a shot.

There is also http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.html if you aready have commons-io in your project.

https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/input/ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java